# Image Histogram Comparison

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying to do histogram image comparison between two RGB images which includes heads of the same persons and non-heads to see the correlation between them. The reason I am doing this is because after performing scanning using HOG to check whether the scanning window is a head or not, I am now trying to track the same head throughout consequent frames and also I want to remove some clear false positives.

I currently tried both RGB and HSV histogram comparison and used Euclidean Distance to check the difference between the histograms. The following is the code I wrote:

```
%RGB histogram comparison

 %clear all;
img1 = imread('testImages/samehead_1.png');
img2 = imread('testImages/samehead_2.png');

img1 = rgb2hsv(img1);
img2 = rgb2hsv(img2);

%% calculate number of bins = root(pixels);
[rows, cols] = size(img1);
no_of_pixels = rows * cols;
%no_of_bins = floor(sqrt(no_of_pixels));
no_of_bins = 256;

%% obtain Histogram for each colour
% -----1st Image---------
rHist1 = imhist(img1(:,:,1), no_of_bins);
gHist1 = imhist(img1(:,:,2), no_of_bins);
bHist1 = imhist(img1(:,:,3), no_of_bins);

hFig = figure;
hold on;
h(1) = stem(1:256, rHist1);
h(2) = stem(1:256 + 1/3, gHist1);
h(3) = stem(1:256 + 2/3, bHist1);

set(h, 'marker', 'none')
set(h(1), 'color', [1 0 0])
set(h(2), 'color', [0 1 0])
set(h(3), 'color', [0 0 1])

hold off;

% -----2nd Image---------
rHist2 = imhist(img2(:,:,1), no_of_bins);
gHist2 = imhist(img2(:,:,2), no_of_bins);
bHist2 = imhist(img2(:,:,3), no_of_bins);

hFig = figure;
hold on;
h(1) = stem(1:256, rHist2);
h(2) = stem(1:256 + 1/3, gHist2);
h(3) = stem(1:256 + 2/3, bHist2);

set(h, 'marker', 'none')
set(h(1), 'color', [1 0 0])
set(h(2), 'color', [0 1 0])
set(h(3), 'color', [0 0 1])

%% concatenate values of a histogram in 3D matrix
% -----1st Image---------
M1(:,1) = rHist1;
M1(:,2) = gHist1;
M1(:,3) = bHist1;

% -----2nd Image---------
M2(:,1) = rHist2;
M2(:,2) = gHist2;
M2(:,3) = bHist2;

%% normalise Histogram
% -----1st Image---------
M1 = M1./no_of_pixels;
% -----2nd Image---------
M2 = M2./no_of_pixels;

%% Calculate Euclidean distance between the two histograms
E_distance = sqrt(sum((M2-M1).^2));
```

The E_distance consists of an array containing 3 distances which refer to the red histogram difference, green and blue.

**The Problem is:**

- When I compare the histogram of a non-head(eg. a bag) with that of a head..there is a clear difference in the error. So this is acceptable and can help me to remove the false positive.
- However! When I am trying to check whether the two images are heads of the same person, this technique did not help at all as the head of another person gave a less Euclidean distance than that of the same person.

Can someone explain to me if I am doing this correctly, or maybe any guidance of what I should do?

PS: I got the idea of the LAB histogram comparison from this paper (Affinity Measures section): [People Looking at each other](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/calvin/Publications/marinIJCV14.pdf)

Comment: Histogram comparison is not very effective for this type of task.   For example, the same person in different lighting would give larger distance than potentially a different person with lighting similar to the compared image.

Comment: I understand...so what would you recommend for bounding boxes affinities? I.e. how would you associate separate detected windows together? Thanks

Comment: Well, since you want to be able to match faces, I would suggest techniques more aligned with face recognition.  Extract descriptors that are used in that domain and compare them.

Comment: As I tried to explain in the question...I already performed the detection part by using HOG + SVM. So currently I am in the stage of post processing..i.e. I am trying to prune the false positives and am trying to associate the  detected windows in separate frames to same persons for tracking.

Comment: I didn't say detection, but recognition.  you can probably start with eigenfaces and work your way up from there.

Comment: I think the problem is that I cannot use eigenfaces due to the fact, that the heads I detect are normally facing sideways, thus I can only see the profile of the head. Any suggestions? Thank you @Photon

Comment: As long as the heads always have the same pose, it shouldn't be a problem to use eigenfaces.  You will need to do your own training, as opposed to use an existing set of vectors, but the math and methods remain valid.  If you have variable pose, then more sophisticated methods are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color histogram similarity may be used as a good clue for tracking by detection, but don't count on it to disambiguate all possible matches between people-people and people-non-people.

According to your code, there is one thing you can do to improve the comparison: currently, you are working with per-channel histograms. This is not discriminative enough because you do not know when R-G-B components co-occur (e.g. you know how many times the red channel is in range 64-96 and how many times the blue is in range 32-64, but not when these occur simultaneously). To rectify this, you must work with 3D histograms, counting the co-occurrence of colors). For a discretization of 8 bins per channel, your histograms will have 8^3=512 bins.

Other suggestions for improvement:

1. Weighted assignment to neighboring bins according to interpolation weights. This eliminates the discontinuities introduced by bin quantization
2. Hierarchical splitting of detection window into cells (1 cell, 4 cells, 16 cells, etc), each with its own histogram, where the histograms of different levels and cells are concatenated. This allows catching local color details, like the color of a shirt, or even more local, a shirt pocket/sleeve.
3. Working with the Earth Mover's Distance (EMD) instead of the Euclidean metric for comparing histograms. This reduces color quantization effects (differences in histograms are weighted by color-space distance instead of equal weights), and allows for some error in the localization of cells within the detection window.
4. Use other cues for tracking. You'll be surprised how much the similarity between the HoG descriptors of your detections helps disambiguate matches!

Comment: Dear @Killogre, regarding this statement: "To rectify this, you must work with 3D histograms, counting the co-occurrence of colors). " Would you be as so kind to explain further with what how I can count the co-occurence of the colors please?

Comment: And what are the number of bins per channel that you recommend please? as according to wikipedia one choice is square root of the number of pixels. But I think these number of bins are too much.

Comment: What I mean is that you have to go over pixels, looking at their RGB (or HSV) values, and calculating the correct bin for each triplet. with 8 bins per channel (recommended), the bin index would be 64*(r/32)+8*(g/32)+b/32. Note these are integer divisions. The simplest histogram just increases the count of this bin.

Comment: Thanks :) And regarding point 4. did you mean that I generate histograms based on by HOG feature vectors, (say using 10 bins) and compare the hists by Euclidean Distance? Thanks for your great assistance.

Comment: Let me correct myself...sorry HOG is already a feature vector in itself...so I just need to compare both HOG vectors using Euclidean distance. Am I right please?

Comment: correct about the comparison of the feature vectors. you can use any metric suitable for comparing histograms: Euclidean, Bhattacharyya, Xi squared. just make sure to find the proper threshold/scaling by plotting the histogram distance values of positive and negative matches

Comment: Dear Killogre, I was reviewing again the Earth's Moving Distance through this link [link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/RUBNER/emd.htm#RUBNER98A). I currently implemented the 2nd point (i.e. I used cellular decomposition to capture local color details). However when reading through the EMD link I found that I can use this metric over the Histogram Intersection metric I am currently using. Can you explain to me how this can be done please as I didn't manage to totally get its point. Thanks in advance Killogre.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of the implementation of the EMD. I know it is a constrained optimization problem, and there are efficient ways to solve it. I don't understand your comment on the histogram intersection kernel. If generic enough, you should phrase it as a question in stack overflow, not a comment

Comment: I understand. No I only meant that I am currently using histogram intersection in order to compare the histograms of Colour Hists (where I am using cellular decomposition to extract them). I am using histogram intersection metric instead of Euclidean distance.

Comment: Histogram intersection is good, but EMD is an improvement, at a computational cost. OpenCV has an implementation of EMD

Comment: Dear @killogre, sorry for bothering you again however I currently have an urgent problem as I am dealing with occlusions. I left a question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052905/calculating-dispersion-in-human-tracking) about the dispersion metric and no one seems to know about it. Can you kindly check it out please? :) I really appreciate you assistance Killogre.