# Calculating dispersion in Human Tracking

Tags: computer-vision, tracking

I am currently trying to track human heads from a CCTV. I am currently using colour histogram and LBP histogram comparison to check the affinity between bounding boxes. However sometimes these are not enough.

I was reading through a paper in the following link : [paper](http://w3.antd.nist.gov/wctg/manet/ciss00.pdf) where **dispersion** metric is described. However I still cannot clearly get it. For example I cannot understand what pi,j is referring to in the equation. Can someone kindly & clearly explain how I can find dispersion between bounding boxes in separate frames please?

You assistance is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper tackles the tracking problem using a background model, as most CCTV tracking methods do. The BG model produces a foreground mask, and the aforementioned p_ij relates to this mask after some morphology. Specifically, they try to separate foreground blobs into components, based on thresholds on allowed 'gaps' in FG mask holes. The end result of this procedure is a set of binary masks, one for each hypothesized object. These masks are then used for tracking using spatial and temporal consistency. In my opinion, this is an old fashioned way of processing video sequences, only relevant if you're limited in processing power and the scenes are not crowded.

To answer your question, if O is the mask related to one of the hypothesized objects, then p_ij is the binary pixel in the (i,j) location within the mask. Thus, c_x and c_y are the center of mass of the binary shape, and the dispersion is simply the average distance from the center of mass for the shape (it is larger for larger objects. This enforces scale consistency in tracking, but in a very weak manner. You can do much better if you have a calibrated camera.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly dispersion is only used to check for size consistency. So for you to understand me, I used HOG + SVM for my detector so that per each frame I extract bounding boxes of were the heads are. Obviously I have some FPs sometimes more than expected. Now I am using colour and LBP histograms to match people and also overlap between each other.  I did not use a state of the art tracker because of the angle of my CCTV. In fact I want to show you two screenshots for you to understand the angle in a comment below. And also the framerate is somewhat slow sometimes 2/3 fps.

Comment: These are the 2 example images :
1). [image 1](http://postimg.org/image/vb7bkty6h/)
2).[image 2](http://postimg.org/image/opylmhbjn/)
So as you can see I am using a scanner which scans for heads of different sizes (128x128, 192x192, and 256x256). 
I am trying to tackle tracking as I told you above. However, although for colour matching I am using 2 level cell decomposition (HSV), sometimes it fails to correlate the same person as I am only taking the head. However I am accepting its failure rate.
My problem is that of occlusion. That is why I posted this question. I was going to try and use.

Comment: ..[continued] dispersion. However, as you explained it only has to do with scale. Do you have any idea how to tackle occlusion in the cases like I showed in the screen shots please? I am currently trying to use a sort of trajectory prediction. However I am still unsure if it makes sense.
Can you assist me in this please? In case you are not with me I am very glad and wish to contact you in a different manner if that's fine with you as you are of great assistance for me.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the proper use of this website. The questions have to be of general nature. I cannot assist you personally.

Comment: I am sorry for that! Will try to make them as general as possible. Excuse me.

Comment: Regarding this question. When you said : " binary pixel in the (i,j) location within the mask" what do you mean by 'binary' pixel? The pixel HSV value?